# Async calls made to openai endpoint from .py file is taking longer than the time taken by same async calls from notebook

Tags: python-asyncio, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to speeden up multiple openai chat completion api calls by calling them asynchronously. While this improvement is visible in jupyter notebook, but when the same code is run in a .py file it is taking way longer.

This is the code that I'm trying to run in both 1) jupyter notebook and 2) python file.
Note: import nest_asyncio and nest_asyncio.apply() are useful only when used in jupyter notebook.

```
import asyncio
import openai
import time
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

openai.api_base = ""
openai.api_version = "2023-09-15-preview"
openai.api_key = ""

prompts = ["What are prime numbers", #some random questions
           "Translate this to Spanish : How are you", 
           "Explain the evolution of milkyway galaxy"]

async def process_prompt(prompt):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    response = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        engine="development",
        messages=[{'role':'user','content':prompt}]
    ))
    return response.choices[0].message['content']

async def main():
    tasks = [process_prompt(prompt) for prompt in prompts]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    
    for result in results:
        print(result)

start=time.time()
asyncio.run(main())
end=time.time()
print('Time take',end-start)
```

The avg time it took in jupyter notebook is around 3.5s.
The avg time it took in python is around 10s.

I even tried another approach using concurrent.futures, but the results were similar.
Why is this happening? Is this because of some restrictions from openai?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem occurred because of execution "nest_asyncio.apply()", since it's purpose is to allow running an event loop inside an environment that may already have an event loop running, such as Jupyter notebooks, but you are using it in a .py script, try to remove it.